# Virtuemart SEF: how to mod_rewrite 301 redirect from router.php to Yagendoo router

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, joomla, virtuemart, joomla-sef-urls

I'm migrating an existing ecommerce site (Joomla 1.5 + Virtuemart) from basic router.php SEF to Yagendoo router plugin (Virtuemart SEO SEF Links Pro). The problem is, the two create different URLs and I don't want to lose current listings, so I thought of creating a mod_rewrite 301 rule.

router.php url

```
http://hostname/it/home/category/<category ID>/<category name>
```

Yagendoo router url

```
http://hostname/it/<category name>
```

I've come up with: RewriteRule ^it/home/category/(.*)$ it/$ [R=301,L] which is almost correct, but still gives me the category number before the name. Does anyone know how I can remove the number but still keep whatever comes afterwards?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

`RewriteRule ^it/home/category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ it/$2 [R=301,L]`

I did not chek it, but it is pretty easy to customize it for your purposes. The main idea is storing  and  in different variables($1, $2).